bash: script running in pm2 unable to access file descriptors files at /dev/fd/
I have script script.sh:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# pm2 seems to always run in `bash` regardless of `#!`
echo "running in $(readlink -f /proc/$$/exe)"

# Redirect to both stdout(1) and stderr(2)
echo "hello" | tee /dev/fd/2

I am running it with pm2 start script.sh
I can see logs at pm2 logs like so:
tee: /dev/fd/2: No such device or address

Which means script is unable to access /dev/fd. Although this problem doesn't happen when directly running in a bash terminal.


About pm2: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/
Previous discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78885319/bash-redirecting-to-multiple-file-descriptors
For reference : file descriptors and /dev/fd


"I can see logs at pm2 logs like so:" ?? where is there a reference to pm2 logs in the text that follows? Maybe you missed a copy/paste? This seems very pm2 specific. Did you look at issues on their github ?

1. Why this Error message?

tee: /dev/fd/2: No such device or address


Is not saying it's not finding /dev/fd, it's saying that trying to open /dev/fd/2 is failing with a ENXIO error code.
You can confirm that error message corresponds to that error code in zsh with:
$ zmodload zsh/system
$ syserror ENXIO
No such device or address

If you look at the open(2) man page on a Linux-based system, the possible reasons for that code are:

ENXIO  O_NONBLOCK | O_WRONLY is set, the named file is a FIFO, and no process has the FIFO open for reading.
ENXIO  The file is a device special file and no corresponding device exists.
ENXIO  The file is a UNIX domain socket.

Here, you're most likely in the last case. It's common for stderr to be  on a UNIX domain socket, that's typically happening for most processes started by systemd where stderr is a UNIX domain socket communicating with journald.
If you run:
sudo lsof -d2 -E

On a typical modern GNU/Linux system, you'll find the fd 2 of most processes are connected to journald via a UNIX domain socket.
And on Linux, /dev/fd/2 is not behaving like on other Unix-like systems.
On other Unix-like systems (except Cygwin which behaves like Linux in this instance), opening /dev/fd/2 or /dev/stderr is like doing a dup(2), so writing to a fd opened on /dev/fd/2 is like writing on fd 2 (stderr), but on Linux, /dev/fd/2 is a magic symlink to the file opened on fd 2, and opening that file anew gives you a totally separate open file description than the one fd 2 is pointing to.
Here, that even fails altogether as one can't open() a UNIX domain socket, one has to connect() to it instead.
But even if fd 2 was opened to a regular file instead, using tee /dev/fd/2 would also have been wrong, as it would have opened the file from the start instead (and possibly in a different mode). In that case, using tee -a helps a bit but not for the UNIX domain socket case.
2. Using zsh instead of bash
Here, you could use zsh instead of bash and do:
#! /usr/bin/env zsh
print -ru2 Running in /proc/self/exe(:P)
echo Hello >&1 >&2

As zsh has builtin support for both readlink -f (or its standard realpath equivalent) and tee. Except its tee (which is done implicitly when a fd is redirected more than once for writing) can write to arbitrary file descriptors and anything zsh can redirect to, and not just files like for tee.
If you can't be sure the she-bang is honoured, change it to:
#! /usr/bin/env zsh
[ -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] || exec zsh -- "$0" "$@"
print -ru2 Running in /proc/self/exe(:P)
echo Hello >&1 >&2

3. Use tee to cat in a ksh-style process substitution.
Using /dev/fd/x for this kind of thing on Linux/Cygwin only really works acceptably when the fd is opened on things like a pipe or a tty device where all writes by different processes are mostly independent from each other and there's no concept of position within the file.
So here with bash, you could do something like:
echo hello | tee -- >(cat >&2)

Where >(cat >&2) expands to a /dev/fd/n (or /proc/self/fd/n which is the same on Linux), but n is a fd open on a pipe here, and what you feed to that pipe is read by cat, and what cat reads from that pipe it writes on its stdout which we've redirected to the same open file description as on stderr.
Beware however that bash doesn't wait for that cat process, so you might find that in:
echo hello | tee >(cat>&2)
echo world >&2

On stderr, world comes before hello as cat has not finished its job by the time bash runs echo world.
